# Programmatically setting a UICollectionViewCell as Selected but indexPathsForSelectedItems.count is 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I programmatically set a custom `UICollectionViewCell` called `CheckCell` to be selected as follows:

```
[self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES];

if ([[self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]) {
   NSLog(@"Selected");
}

NSLog(@"%i",[self.myCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems].count);
```

The first NSLog prints "Selected" leading me to believe the cell at `IndexPath` is indeed selected.  However, the result of the second NSLog is 0.  Why is the selected cell's index not being added to `indexPathsForSelectedItems`?

Comment: self.myCollectionView and myCollectionView are identical? (you are using both variants!)

Comment: yes they are the same, sorry editing mistake, I will update the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the answer.

Call `selectItemAtIndexPath` instead of `[self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:YES];`

**Example Code:**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;

[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];

if ([[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]) {

    NSLog(@"selected count %i",[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems].count);
}
```

**OutPut**

```
selected count 1
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't result in a call the delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Have to do that manually.